# One table with two for foreign key, how to set on delete cascade

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have four tables which I named as T1,T2,T3,T4. Now I set reference T1->T2->T3->T4, and set with on delete cascade property, it's ok. But When I set T1->T3 and also with on delete cascade property, sqlserver report error, the error looks like 'cause cycle cascade or multiple cascade'.
My question is: Parts of records in T3 really belongs to T2 and parts of records in T3 really belongs to T1, if one record in T3 belongs to T1, it will never belongs to T2. How can I express such relationship?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like `T3` contains entities that are not all the same thing, if some belong to `T1` and some to `T2`.  They may have the same structure, but they aren't really the same thing.

As far as how to express such a relationship:  Well, you can split `T3` into two different tables.  That would allow your delete cascades to work.

Or, if you're determined to keep `T3` one table, you can experiment with delete triggers.

The core problem is that only you know the if-it-belongs-to-T1-it-can't-belong-to-T2 condition:  there's no way to represent that through foreign keys alone.  To represent that, you need logic, which is where the trigger comes in.

If you find that there are other columns in `T3` that only apply when the record belongs to `T1` and are null when the record belongs to `T2`, and vice versa, then it suggests that, however similar the records look otherwise, they really are separate entities logically.

Comment: Hi Ann L., I think you really understood what I talk about, I'm so worry about  my English language.

Comment: Hi Ann L., I think you really understood what I talk about, I'm so worry about  my English language. The record belongs to T1 and T2 has same struct, the record is something like config option, same struct but different value. So I merge them into one table, and I also think they are not separate entities logically. Now it seemed I can not separated these in table struct, would like tell me how to use delete triggers? I'll use it in EF4. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, if `T3` contains configuration options, maybe `T3` shouldn't have a foreign key relationship to `T1` or `T2`:  they should have a relationship to `T3`!  They should reference `T3`'s key rather than `T3` referencing `T1` or `T2`'s key.

Comment: Also, here is an article that talks about delete triggers as an alternative to cascading deletes, by Itzik Ben-Gan:  http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/cascading-alternatives.